# (About) When Noetic feature freeze in core libraries

Tags: ros, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a planned date for the freeze for the new feature for ROS Noetic?

This might not be accurate, but in ROS core libraries development, pull requests that contain new features are not accepted to the already-released distros, as far as I'm aware for the last few years (and I appreciate that for the stability perspective).

Knowing the date of the new feature freeze (as well as bugfixes), even roughly,  would motivate contributes to close as many new feature proposal as possible (at least me and my team, or anyone who's thinking to switch to the new distro).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346432/(about)-when-noetic-feature-freeze-in-core-libraries/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2020-03-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In short, there is no freeze date for any ROS 1 packages. It is up to the individual package maintainers to decide. However, I recommend trying to get features in before **April 8th**.

In practice, many maintainers of packages one would consider "core" in ROS 1 place a very high value on stability. I would only count on them releasing bug fixes after ROS Noetic's release date ([May 23rd, 2020](https://www.worldturtleday.org/)). If your team would like to get new features into ROS Noetic, the risk of a change not making it into the ROS distro increases as it gets closer to the release date.

This is different for ROS 2. ROS 2 distros do have a freeze date for packages in `ros_core`. [Foxy Fitzroy](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Releases/Release-Foxy-Fitzroy/#id14) is releasing on the same day as ROS Noetic and has a freeze date of **April 8th**. I would try to get changes in before the Foxy freeze since many maintainers of the core packages in ROS 1 also work on core packages in ROS 2.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2020-03-13**:
Thank you. And looks like the noetic branches has been readily available on some core repos e.g. [ros_comm](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/tree/noetic-devel)!